# How to remove rows if a value of cell appears in another column's cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file like this.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| dog_b | dog_k,cat_a |
| cat_a | cat |
| fish |  |
| bird_c |  |
| elephant | bird_c |

I am just trying to remove rows if df['A'] includes in df['B']. cat and bird in column A appear in column B so they should be removed.
The output should be like this.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| dog_b | dog_k,cat_a |
| fish |  |
| elephant | bird_c |

I tried to:

```
b = df['B']
df = df[~(df['A'].isin(b.values))]
```

but it did not worked and gives output table as before(first).

Comment: If not working seems data related problem, what is `print (df.head().to_dict(orient='list'))` ?

Comment: The output is like this: {'A': ['dog_b', 'cat_a', 'fish', 'bird_c', 'elephant'], 'B': ['dog_k,cat_a', 'cat', nan, nan, 'bird_c']}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex and [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df['B'].str.split(',').explode()
                                         .dropna().unique())
                   )

out = df[~df['A'].str.contains(pattern)]
```

Output:

```
          A            B
0     dog_b  dog_k,cat_a
2      fish          NaN
4  elephant       bird_c
```

Comment: It just worked for bird_c (the row of bird_c is removed) . I edit the data. Do you think the problem could be because of that?

Comment: See update for a filter based on a substring

Comment: Actually there is something wrong. It works for this data. But, for example if I add a new row and first cell includes "dog_k", then when I run the code it does not remove "dog_k". Why?